# Docker to Run Small Java Class: Could Not Find Or Load Main Class (Even Though It Exists)

Tags: java, docker

I realize that this question may already have been asked, but in my research I can't find an answer.  I'm probably making a simple mistake.

I would like to run a Java class locally with Docker, inside a container.  Below is my Dockerfile:

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM maven:3.5.2-jdk-8

COPY src /src

RUN javac src/java/com/Main.java
CMD java src/java/com/Main
```

I then run these commands in order:

```
docker build -t my_image_6_26_19:latest .
docker run -it my_image_6_26_19:latest
```

The `build` command runs fine, but the `run` command throws the following error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class src.java.com.Main
```

I have reviewed the following questions on SO, but no answers seem to work (or maybe I didn't catch the solution):

- [Buildning docker image from Dockerfile with maven - Error: "Could not find or load main class"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49922516/buildning-docker-image-from-dockerfile-with-maven-error-could-not-find-or-lo)
- [DockerFile to run a java program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35291076/dockerfile-to-run-a-java-program)
- [Docker Error: Could not find or load Main class Main.Main](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54144292/docker-error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-main-main)

When I build the container, through some debugging (`RUN ls /src/java/com`) I can see that a file `Main.class` is being created.  I'm not sure why that file can't be found.  Additionally, I have tried changing the last line of my Dockerfile to `CMD java src/java/com/Main.class`, but no luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `Main` doesn't have a package try:

```
 CMD java -classpath src/java/com Main
```

if it does have a package (e.g. `com`, perhaps?) try:

```
CMD java -classpath src/java com.Main
```

Answer (score 1):

The second version in answer from @martijno is the corect one. I additionally recommend telling the compiler to write the output into another directory, e.g. `bin`:

```
RUN javac src/java/com/Main.java -d bin
CMD java -cp bin com.Main
```